# casting an object to char and then "uncasting it back"

Tags: c++, casting, char

If you have an object

```
struct Packet P;
```

that consists of

```
struct Packet {
    struct Packet_header header;
    unsigned char data[MAXIMUM_BUFFER_LENGTH];
};
```

and the header consists of

```
struct Packet_header {
    unsigned int checksum;
    unsigned int seq;
    unsigned int ack;
    unsigned int data_length;
};
```

If I try to cast the packet

```
(unsigned char*) &P
```

is there anyway I can "uncast" back to get my original packet P?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*) &P;
Packet *pPacket = (Packet *)p;
```

Comment: He wants the cast back to `Packet`, not `Packet*`.

Answer (score 3):

The easy way would be to use `reinterpret_cast<Packet>(*(reinterpret_cast<Packet*>(pUC)))`, where `pUC` is the `unsigned char*`.

The **correct** ways is to have, in `Packet_header`, a conversion constructor and a cast operator (or cast-like method):

```
struct Packet_header {
    Packet_header(unsigned char*);  //construct object form unsigned char*
    operator unsigned char*();      //cast it back
    const unsigned char* getUC();   //or get an unsigned char*

    unsigned int checksum;
    unsigned int seq;
    unsigned int ack;
    unsigned int data_length;
};
```

Comment: Thanks!, how would use the cast operator and the conversion constructor? I'm kind of a newbie in c++. An example would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, theoretically you can do that.
Since both `Packet*` and `unsigned char*` are pointer to data types, there is no information loss happening (if one of them is a function pointer then it's possible that information could be lost).

Few things to note:

- Avoid such typecasting in first place
- It's better to typecast to/from `void*` for genericness; at while casting to `void*` you don't have to use typecasting
- Use `reinterpret_cast<>` to show the reader that something 'dirty' is
  happening